# Problems with compiling apache 2.4.33 on Debian Wheezy

Tags: apache-2.4, debian-wheezy

I have problems compiling apache's latest release 2.4.33 on a Debian system.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache_2.4.33 --enable-suexec --with-suexec-caller=nobody --enable-module=so --with-suexec-docroot=/httpd --enable-rewrite --enable-ssl --with-mpm=prefork
```

Last lines of the make output:

```
/usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -pthread      -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE     -I. -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/os/unix -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/include -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1 -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/aaa -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/cache -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/core -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/database -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/filters -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/ldap -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/loggers -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/lua -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/proxy -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/session -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/ssl -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/test -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/server -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/md -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/arch/unix -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/dav/main -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/generators -I/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/mappers -prefer-pic -c md_json.c && touch md_json.slo
md_json.c: In function ‘md_json_setb’:
md_json.c:279:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘json_boolean’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
md_json.c:279:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘jselect_set_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
md_json.c:217:21: note: expected ‘struct json_t *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
md_json.c: In function ‘md_json_geta’:
md_json.c:587:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘json_array_foreach’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
md_json.c:587:39: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
md_json.c: In function ‘md_json_itera’:
md_json.c:663:39: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
md_json.c: In function ‘md_json_getsa’:
md_json.c:688:43: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
md_json.c: In function ‘md_json_dupsa’:
md_json.c:711:43: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
md_json.c: In function ‘md_json_readb’:
md_json.c:937:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘json_load_callback’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
md_json.c:937:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
md_json.c: In function ‘md_json_readf’:
md_json.c:973:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
make[4]: *** [md_json.slo] Fehler 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/md'
make[3]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Fehler 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules/md'
make[2]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Fehler 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33/modules'
make[1]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Fehler 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/install/httpd-2.4.33'
make: *** [all-recursive] Fehler 1
```

Up to 2.4.29 no compile problems on this system. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely missing a dependency for the mod_md module. Do you have `libjansson-dev` installed?

Comment: Yes it's installed. I guess without it "configure" will terminate with an error: aptitude show libjansson-dev
Package: libjansson-dev
New: yes
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: same
Version: 2.3.1-2+deb7u1
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Maintainer: Alessandro Ghedini <ghedo@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 134 k
Depends: libjansson4 (= 2.3.1-2+deb7u1)
Breaks: libjansson-dev (!= 2.3.1-2+deb7u1)
Replaces: libjansson-dev (< 2.3.1-2+deb7u1)